# PHP Apply multiple callback functions when using array_map, array_walk etc. functions

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, array-map

I have encountered an array of serialized values like below:

```
Array
(
    [primary] => Array
        (
            [key_type_0_key_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27232";}
            [key_type_1_key_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27231";}
            [key_type_2_key_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27147";}
            [key_type_3_key_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27157";}
        )

    [additional] => Array
        (
            [key_type_0_key_othername] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27169";}
            [key_type_1_key_othername] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27160";}
            [key_type_2_key_othername] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27103";}
            [key_type_3_key_othername] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27149";}
        )
)
```

Now I need to apply two functions namely, `unserialize` and `array_shift` in specified order to extract the scalar values like `27169` and store in another `array`, how can I do that in **one pass** of `array_map` or I have to run `array_map` two times compulsorily ?

Also one problem is with recursion, only `array_walk_recursive` handles recursion properly, but in my case if I try below code, I am getting the given error:

```
return array_walk_recursive($array, function ( &$value ) {
        $value = array_shift( unserialize( $value ) );
    });
```

Error:

```
 Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /path/to/file.php on line 367
```

Expected Result:

```
Array
(
    [primary] => Array
        (
            27232
            27231
            27147
            27157
        )

    [additional] => Array
        (
            27169
            27160
            27103
            27149
        )
)
```

Comment: who told you can do that in one pass in first place and why it is that really makes a difference?

Comment: It was just a thought and try, as I have a large array(lot larger than the one mentioned in question) also read my updated question, if it may help

Comment: If you store the unserialized value in a variable and then do the array_shift it will fix the should be passed by reference error.

Comment: As you see, sub-array keys if can be maintained be well and good, but they aren't as important but the values are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no calls to array_map.

```
<?php

$data = [
    'primary' =>
    [
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27232";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27231";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27147";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27157";}'
    ],
    'additional' =>
    [
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27169";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27160";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27103";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27149";}'
    ]
];



$numbers = [];
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $k=>$v) {
        $unserialized = unserialize($v);
        $numbers[$key][] = (int) array_shift($unserialized);
    }
}

var_dump($numbers);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'primary' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 27232
      1 => int 27231
      2 => int 27147
      3 => int 27157
  'additional' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 27169
      1 => int 27160
      2 => int 27103
      3 => int 27149
```

Here a mutating array_walk example with three array_map calls.  Far uglier and harder to read in my eyes, but each their own:

```
array_walk($data, function(&$v) {
        $v = array_map('intval', array_map('array_shift', array_map('unserialize', $v)));
    }
);
var_dump($data);
```

Output:

```
    array (size=2)
      'primary' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 27232
          1 => int 27231
          2 => int 27147
          3 => int 27157
      'additional' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => int 27169
          1 => int 27160
          2 => int 27103
          3 => int 27149
```

Comment: Thanks for a `foreach` based answer, but can this be done with array_map or `array_walk_recursive`, I have used those functions for most of my array operations and I don't want to break the trend frankly.

Comment: @VST, array_walk_recursive works on leaf nodes, so more difficult to associate keys.  I've added an array_walk example.

Comment: It's ok, as I said, the sub-array keys are not important, thanks for `array_walk` example.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to answer the question that was asked.  Yes, yes you can... and you nearly had it!

You only needed to change the way that you were accessing the value.  Replace the `array_shift()` call with `[0]` -- this eliminates the Strict Standards error.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a20810e23857becfcee0bf21ab288a8bfef3d18e))

```
$array=[
    'primary' =>
    [
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27232";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27231";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27147";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27157";}'
    ],
    'additional' =>
    [
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27169";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27160";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27103";}',
        'a:1:{i:0;s:5:"27149";}'
    ]
];
array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$v){$v=unserialize($v)[0];});
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'primary' => 
  array (
    0 => '27232',
    1 => '27231',
    2 => '27147',
    3 => '27157',
  ),
  'additional' => 
  array (
    0 => '27169',
    1 => '27160',
    2 => '27103',
    3 => '27149',
  ),
)
```

Comment: That's far healthier than my attempt at an array_walk and array_map codge-up.